# ElasticSearch update to child document not updating parent document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way in ElasticSearch to automatically update all parent documents when a child document has its properties changed? Maybe I'm way of track about how I'm using ElasticSearch. The code:

```
        var child = new Child
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Child"
        };

        var parent = new Parent
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Parent",
            Child = child
        };

        var nestedResponse = client.CreateIndex("index", i => i
            .Mappings(m => m
                .Map<Parent>(map => map
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(ps => ps
                        .Nested<Child>(n => n
                            .Name(p => p.Child)
                            .AutoMap()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        var indexResult = client.Index<Parent>(parent);
        indexResult = client.Index<Child>(child);

        var reloadedParent = client.Get<Parent>(parent.Id.ToString()).Source;
        var childName = reloadedParent.Child.Name;
        child.Name = "child changed";
        var updateRequest = new UpdateRequest<Child, Child>("index", typeof(Child), child.Id);
        updateRequest.Doc = child;

        var reindexResult = client.Update<Child>(updateRequest);

        var reloadedParentAfterChildChange = client.Get<Parent>(parent.Id.ToString()).Source;
        var childChangedName = reloadedParentAfterChildChange.Child.Name;

        Assert.AreEqual(child.Name, childChangedName);

    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Child can belong to many different Parents. Is there any way to have the changes to the Child be propagated to all the Parents that contain the Child? I'm using the Nest client from c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not quite right.

1. In the mapping, you set up `Child` property as a nested type, but then index both `parent` and `child`.

   A nested type is indexed on the type on which it is *nested*, that is, the json representing the `Child` property on `parent` is indexed as part of the parent json document.

   It is possible to have a [Parent/Child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html) in Elasticsearch with a one parent to many children, which sounds like you would need to invert the Parent/Child roles within your model to use.
2. Following indexing, you get the source of the `parent` document, change the child name of the child on the parent, but then update the child document you have indexed, *without* updating the `parent` *with* the child.

   Many documents can have the same nested document values, but there will be no relationship between these documents therefore updating the values would require an update on each document. This can be done with the [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html).

Here's an *example* to demonstrate; in production, you probably don't want to disable direct streaming, log out all request/responses, call refresh after each operation, etc.

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
            .PrettyJson()
            .DisableDirectStreaming()
            .OnRequestCompleted(response =>
                {
                    // log out the request
                    if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            $"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri} \n" +
                            $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri}");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    // log out the response
                    if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                                 $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                                 $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                                 $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                    }
                });

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var child = new Child
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Child"
    };

    var parent = new Parent
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Parent",
        Child = child
    };

    var anotherParent = new Parent
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Another Parent",
        Child = child
    };

    var nestedResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, i => i
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Parent>(map => map
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(nn => nn.Id)
                        .NotAnalyzed()
                    )
                    .Nested<Child>(n => n
                        .Name(p => p.Child)
                        .AutoMap()
                        .Properties(p => p
                            .String(s => s
                                .Name(nn => nn.Id)
                                .NotAnalyzed()
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var indexResult = client.Index<Parent>(parent);
    indexResult = client.Index<Parent>(anotherParent);

    var fetchedParent = client.Get<Parent>(parent.Id).Source;
    var fetchedAnotherParent = client.Get<Parent>(anotherParent.Id).Source;

    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    var update = client.UpdateByQuery<Parent>(u => u
        .Query(q => q
            .Nested(n => n
                .Path(p => p.Child)
                .Query(qq => qq
                    .Term(t => t.Child.Id, child.Id)
                )
            )
        )
        .Script("ctx._source.child.name='New Child Name'")
        .Conflicts(Conflicts.Abort)
        .WaitForCompletion()
        .Refresh()
    );

    fetchedParent = client.Get<Parent>(parent.Id).Source;
    fetchedAnotherParent = client.Get<Parent>(anotherParent.Id).Source;
}


public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child Child { get; set;} 
}

public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works... its a bit messy when the child can belong to different types of parent... like a client can belong to a project, an order etc

Comment: Elasticsearch is extremely good for search, analytics and handling big data at scale with great performance. It is not a relational datastore however, so may require a redesign in how you model your data.